# Create Custom Public Google Map with Markers

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, maps

I have a discord bot written in c# that reports events based on their latitude/longitude. I want to take the latitude/longitude data and place markers on an html based google map (locally hosted or online) using c#

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/).